# Can I avoid network shuffle when creating a KeyedStream from a pre-partitioned Kinesis Data Stream in Apache Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-analytics

Is it possible to create a `KeyedStream` from a pre-sharded/pre-partitioned Kinesis Data Stream without the need for a network shuffle (i.e. using `reinterpretAsKeyedStream` or something similar)?

- If that is not possible (i.e. the only reliable is to consume from Kinesis and then use `keyBy`), then is network shuffling at least minimized by doing a `keyBy` on a the field that the source is sharded by (e.g. `env.addSource(source).keyBy(pojo -> pojo.getTransactionId())`, where the source is a kinesis data stream that is sharded by `transactionId`)
- If the above is possible, what are the limitations?

**What I've Learned so Far**

- The functionality I am describing is already implemented by `reinterpretAsKeyedStream`, but this feature is experimental and seems to have significant drawbacks (as per discussions in the stackoverflow posts below)

  - reinterpretAsStream docs: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/experimental/
  - [Using KeyBy vs reinterpretAsKeyedStream() when reading from Kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72629086/using-keyby-vs-reinterpretaskeyedstream-when-reading-from-kafka)
  - [Apache Flink - how to align Flink and Kafka sharding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73278930/apache-flink-how-to-align-flink-and-kafka-sharding)
- In addition to the above, all the discussions related to `reinterpretAsKeyedStream` that I've found are in the context of Kafka, so I'm not sure how the outcomes differ for a Kinesis Data Stream

**Context of my Application**

- Re. configurations: both the Kinesis Data Stream and Flink will be hosted serverlessly, and automatically scale up/down depending on load (which as I understand it, means that `reinterpretAsKeyedStream` cannot be used)

Any help/insight is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I'm curious why you're worried about this. Are you encountering performance issues caused by the `.keyBy()` shuffle?

Comment: I am not encountering performance issues, but rather looking into steps to make my app as performant as possible. Logically, there should be no need for the shuffle to happen, so I was hoping this could be a way to boost performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there's any way to easily do what you want, at least not in a way that's resilient to changes in the parallelism of your source and your cluster. I have used helicopter stunts to achieve something similar to this, but it involved fragile code (depends on exactly how Flink handles partitioning).